# 'init' has been renamed to 'init(describing:)' in XCode8

Tags: swift, xcode8, swift-playground

It's really going crazy, this single simple line doesn't compile, why?
[image]

I'm using Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)
Here's the api reference for [`String(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1417691-init)

Comment: That API references clearly states at the top: "**Foundation** > String> init(format:_:)" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `import Foundation` to the top of your playground.

This will import the Foundation Framework and will allow you to use its API.

Answer (score -1):

It's really embarrassing to find that [`String(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1417691-init) is part of `Foundation` and not an default constructor....

The solution is that put `import Foundation` on the top of the playground